# AWS S3 Running on the same EC2

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a service that is running on the same instance where the AWS-S3 is running, in this case I don't have to provide credentials when pushing a file to an S3 bucket.

Here is the code I have, but it shows me this error:

```
message: 'Access Denied',
code: 'AccessDenied',
region: null,
time: 2019-12-13T22:30:56.325Z,
requestId: '3F6AA6FAC6787B36',
extendedRequestId:'yQ4y6uthaTDBr6SuoXbI0g0cLWY40SWleATXrBijKrAbhcmsWTYAL+wCBlZpPM/6ytRc8qbIJP4=',
cfId: undefined,
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 44.582589819600926
```

Here is the code:

```
public async writeFileToS3(datasetFile: any): Promise<boolean> {
        try {
            this.s3Bucket = new S3({ region: 'us-east-1' });
            const readFile = this.util.promisify(this.fileWriter.readFile);
            const unlinkFile = this.util.promisify(this.fileWriter.unlink);
            const s3BucketName = this.appConfig.get<string>(
                'infra.fileWriter.bucket'
            );
            const data = await readFile(datasetFile.path);
            const params = {
                Bucket: s3BucketName,
                Key: datasetFile.originalname,
                Body: data,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };

            return await new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
                this.s3Bucket.upload(params, function(err: any) {
                    unlinkFile(datasetFile.path);
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('await call: ' + err);
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw new OperationError('Error writing file to S3');
        }
```

Note: The AWS is configured well, because I have another service that is using Python to interact with S3 and it works fine, but this service is using aws-sdk for Javascript.

Comment: AWS SDK functions can be promisified like so: `upload(params).promise()`.

Comment: @jarmod .. I guess this is not the problem, the problem is telling S3 not to use credentials.

Comment: Right, that was just an FYI. You just need to dig into why you're providing the wrong credentials or why, perhaps, the S3 bucket's policy is denying you access. By the way you have some strange naming conventions that aren't ideal - `this.s3Bucket` is presumably an SDK client S3 object, not a bucket, for example. Typically this code would look like: `const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); const s3 = new AWS.S3(); await s3.upload(params).promise()`.

Comment: @basel.ai What makes you think "you don't have to provide credentials when pushing a file to an S3 bucket"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein because, and simply, it's configured for that! and as I mentioned in the question that I have another service written in python and I'm not passing any credentials, but the issue is with aws-sdk for nodejs, I need to tell it not to look for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed, it was because of providing the `region` and the `ACL`.
simply just removing them fixed the issue.